# Question about Caratheodory extension theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I know that if $\mu$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure defined on an algebra $A$ of subsets of $\Omega$ then there exists a unique measure $\bar\mu$ defined on the generated sigma-algebra i.e $\sigma(A)$ such that $\bar\mu|A=\mu$.
My question: Is the theorem will still be true if we have a measure on semi-algebra, can we extend it to the sigma-algebra generated by the semi-algebra?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! For a proof, see Theorem 1.53 from Achim Klenke's *[Probability Theory: A Comprehensive Course](https://antivirus.uclv.edu.cu/update/libros/Mathematics%20and%20Statistics/Probability%20Theory%20-%20Achim%20Klenke%2C%202nd%20ed.%202014%20-%20978-1-4471-5361-0.pdf)* (the notation $\sigma(\mathcal{A})$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the semiring $\mathcal{A}$). In fact, it holds under even weaker conditions in the sense that we can start from a semiring, and the set function to be extended does not even need to be $\sigma$-additive on the semiring.

Comment: @jeniffer Did this answer your question?